# Unable To Do Inline Edits In A List View

Tags: administration, list-view

I am new to my organization as an admin.
They were able to make quick edits to the fields within a list view on the "Project" object.
But for some reason they can't anymore.

**The "CSM" profile users are the ones that usually do edits from list view. Here is the profile object access:**

[image]

**The list view is showing this message:**

[image]

**I checked the settings under the User Interface in Setup and it is enabled:**

[image]

**The Project object is not using any record types. Please advise!**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are not using record types,
but are you sure there are none created check in object manager just being cautious?

And if there are none just in the list view filter set recordtype equals blank (its mentioned in the docs)

[image]

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000323035&type=1

Comment: So It looks like that the Project object has one record type (Which the "Analyst" profile is using). I don't want to remove that record type, but I do want all CSM profile users to be able to edit all of their list views. How can I do that without going to each list view and adding that "Record Type EQUALS blank" filter? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: No you will have to do it for all list views , but you can differentiate which list views you want the CSM profile, or Analyst profile to see (that way you can use the record type for this profile)